# Use a variable in a for loop for a panel or textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set the text in textboxes to something like A B C and so on, so I am trying to use a for loop to have something like the code below

```
string alpha = "abcdef.."
for (int i = 1; i <= number +1; i++)
{
  textboxi.text = .alpha.CharAt(i)
}
```

"textboxi" dose not work. textbox + i dose not work idir, would anyone have any ideas

Thanks for the help

Comment: what's the value of `number`?

Comment: How are your textboxes organized? Do you have a list or some other container of textboxes, or do they just happen to be named `textbox1`, `textbox2`, etc.? You'll need them to be in a container if you want to access one of them programmatically. An array of textboxes would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Is this the actual code you're working with?

Comment: I'm curious as to what the `sting` class definition looks like.

A more serious, but still unrelated statement: I love IntelliSense.

Comment: Not the code I am working with, just rough example of what I am trying to get at

Comment: I see your edit -- your code still does not compile. Please show us the actual code you're working with. We cannot reproduce your issue with this code. Define "does not work". Compile error (which I suspect)? Runtime exception? What is the error/exception? Where is it happening? Have you googled the error/exception and made an effort to understand what it is and why it's happening? What are you even trying to do to begin with? A lot of questions you need to answer for us to help you.

Comment: if it's not the code you are working with yet an example of what you are trying to get as you put it...then why not update your question to make it more specific as to what you are trying to do.. I am assuming based on the example you are new to C#..?

Comment: Please confirm if this is true. You have an certain number of textboxes. You want for each one set its text property with a letter taken progressively from the string alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got some number of textboxes named `textbox1`, `textbox2`, etc., you can't just put a variable in the name and have it refer to the right textbox. You should put the textboxes in an array first.

```
TextBox[] textboxArray = new TextBox[] { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, ... };
string alpha = "acdefde";
for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
{
    textboxArray[i].Text = alpha[i].ToString();
}
```

### EDIT

Note that this does *no error checking whatsoever*, so if you give it a string that's too long it'll blow up. That's not that big an issue here where the length of both items are known at compile time, but nevertheless here's a fix: change `i < array.Length` to `i < array.Length && i < textboxArray.Length`. If you were to put this into a more general function, I'd have it throw an exception if the number of textboxes given isn't exactly equal to the length of the string given.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string alpha = "abcdef.."
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= number +1; i++)
{
  sb.Append (alpha.CharAt(i));
}
textbox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

**EDIT**: 
My answer missed that you're trying to assign a letter per textbox, as the comment suggests.
So, **Jack**'s answer is the right one, but I highly suggest you do some thinking about your code, because it smells funny (not in a good way). besides, if the text will not be of the same length of the textboxes, it'll throw an exception.

Comment: I think this solution (while perhaps not ideal) would likely solve the issue with a *tiny* modification.  Might I suggest using the [Control.FindControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: why do you think you need a stringbuilder..? just curious..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE running a loop on strings, is usually silly , since strings are immutable

Comment: @JoshuaShearer about the Control, you're probably right. I've actually missed the `i` at the end of his textbox, gosh, that's some bad written code.